# JS Promise in vue shows as undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, es6-promise

I have a promise that return once a correct event is called with the correct action. This is what I have so far

```
 import {EventBus} from "./EventBus";



export function completed()  {
    EventBus.$on('queue-action', e => {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            if(e.action == 'completed'){
                let item = e.queueItem
                resolve(item);
            }else{
                reject(new Error('No action specified in event object'))
            }

        })
    });
}



export function emitAction(action, queueItem)  {
    EventBus.$emit('queue-action', {
        action,
        queueItem
    });
}
```

When calling the completed function in one of my components like this

```
completed()
            .then((item)=> console.log('promise'))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error) );
```

it returns undefined once I add the then and catch methods to this function. It looks like the problem is with me then and catch, but I am unable to determine what it is. From what I have seen online whatever variable you use for the data you use in the then statement.

What I am trying to do is let an element in the "queue" to emit an event to the to the queue with an action for example completed. The queue should then resolve the promise to edit the queue in the intended purpose of that action or react to an error from the promise.

This is what I have done so far

```
import {EventBus} from "./EventBus";
export class QueueEvent {
    constructor(){}
    emitAction(action, queueItem){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            EventBus.$emit('queue-action', {
                action,
                queueItem
            },resolve,reject);
        });
    }
}
export class QueueEvents extends QueueEvent{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    listenForComplete() {
    }
}
```

Comment: `function completed()` doesn't return anything. I would expect `completed().then(...)` to throw `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` here.

Answer (score 0):

Your completed function is not returning a promise (it is returning undefined as you noticed).
You are returning the promise for the event emitter when the queue-action is called. You are defining a new function here: `e => {` and that function that is returning a promise is passed to the `EventBus` event emitter

Comment: How do I get access to that promise then?

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap the whole `EventBus.$on()` in your promise, like this:

```
export function completed()  {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        EventBus.$on('queue-action', e => {
            if(e.action == 'completed'){
                let item = e.queueItem
                resolve(item);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

As a rule of thumb, unless you have a very specific reason to do something else, a function returning a promise should have all it's body wrapped in `return new Promise(...);`. It is also normal and ok to have a lot of code wrapped inside a promise.

Note to the code: I removed `reject` part both for brevity and because I'm not sure that is what you want to do. Unless it is an error if some action happens before `'completed'`, you should just ignore such an event.

Comment: So a child can emit an item to the parent queue component. I was thinking of completed being the listener to those events. Should I have to child return the promise and the parent resolve the promise?

Comment: @Dylan I'm not sure I follow. Why would the parent resolve a promise from its child? I'm also not sure if it has anything really to do with your original question?

Comment: @dylan Well I am making a queue component and the items in the queue component can emit a promis to the parent or the main queue to resolve it. For example a child element can emit a pomise with a queue action event with action of completed the parent would resolve this, but if the action of the event was for example delete the parent would catch a generic error. THats basically what I am trying to do .

Comment: @Dylan I see now that you edited the question and added a new part with a new question. Please don't do that, if you have a second question, ask a second question. Besides, it seems like you are abusing the events dispatch system. It seems like you should be using explicit callbacks instead, or maybe depend on Vue's reactivity instead (this is a blind guess, I have no idea how you use Vue).